# Mostrar output en consola y .txt redireccionado

Tags: c, ip, ping

Por más que intente, no logro redireccionar a .txt lo que obtengo de la ejecución de mi aplicación en C.
Si uso freopen, no muestra el resultado del bucle en consola; si uso una concatenación de "< out.txt" antes de lanzar el "system(str);", no funciona el bucle entero (sólo almacena la segunda línea en .txt, que no aparece por consola, y la primera no queda guardada pero sí aparece en pantalla). Hasta ahora lo que tengo:

```
{

    FILE* fp;
    char ch[500], x[500], str[500], line[BUFSIZ];
    char term[20] = "Media";

    printf("\n    Escribe la ruta del documento deseado\n\n");
    scanf("%s", x);

    fp = fopen(x, "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("El archivo no se ha podido encontrar.");
        exit(0);
    }

    while (fgets(ch, sizeof(ch), fp))
    {
        printf("%s", ch);
    }

    rewind(fp);

    while (fgets(ch, sizeof(ch), fp) != NULL) {
        strcpy(str, "ping ");
        strcat(str, ch);
        system(str);
            }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué quieres redireccionar exactamente? ¿todo? ¿solo la salida del ping?

Comment: Todo lo que muestra la pantalla (stdout), es decir, a partir del lanzamiento del bucle que contiene los ping. Gracias.